# Add App Config To Windows Form app

Tags: .net, winforms, app-config

i am fallowing this path for adding app Config to my project

> #
>
> On the Project menu, click Add New
>   Item.
>
> The Add New Item dialog box appears.
>   #
>
> Select the Application Configuration
>   File template and then click Add.
>
> A file named app.config is added to
>   your project

but there is no app.config in Add New ITem Dialog!
why?
i am using visual Studio 2010 
VB.NET WIndows Form.[image: Here is shot from Add New Item]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is available under General templates